# Python error in dnfdragora update - fedora 27

Tags: fedora, python, upgrade, dnf

I was trying to do an update using the `dnfdragora` dialog, in `fedora 27`.
Until a few days ago I didn't experience any issue.

Today though, when trying to open it I got the following error

[image]

```
> g-io-error-quark:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python._libpycomps.ParserError:
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in
> _message_cb retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords) File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnfdaemon/server/__init__.py", line
> 83, in newFunc rc = func(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/share/dnfdaemon/dnfdaemon-system", line 572, in GetGroups value
> = self.get_groups() File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnfdaemon/server/__init__.py", line
> 250, in get_groups self._load_comps() File
> "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnfdaemon/server/__init__.py", line
> 757, in _load_comps self.base.read_comps() File
> "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 550, in
> read_comps self._comps._add_from_xml_filename(decompressed) File
> "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/comps.py", line 328, in
> _add_from_xml_filename ret = comps.fromxml_f(fn) _libpycomps.ParserError: Fatal parser error (36)
```

It seems that there is something wrong with `Python` but I can't seem to be able to find out what happened and how to fix it.

Any idea would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with a xml file of the updates repository. Try :

```
dnf --repo updates group --> error
dnf --repo fedora group --> no error
```

You can also try to disable the updates repository - waiting for a working updates repository.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

1. `sudo dnf clean all`
2. `dnfdragora`